# "e" undefined Google Script error

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently asked this question:
[Have a listbox populate with every folder in myDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132837/have-a-listbox-populate-with-every-folder-in-mydrive)

I got an answer (Thanks to Serge insas for the help!) But I am trying to get what he made into my current UI. I have the listbox made and everything but the function that he made called, "function folderSelect" when I try and move it over to my UI gives me a "e undefined" error when I run the script. I also need to make sure that when I select that folder in the drop down menu, that when the document is generated, it saves that document in that folder. (sorry that I have asked so many questions about all of this. I try to give it a try myself doing what I need to do before I come here but it is hard when I have no idea what I am doing.)

PasteBin for current project: http://pastebin.com/GVSvfcqG

Here is what I have so far:

```
 function getTemplates() {
      var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Generate from template');
      // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
      var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
      grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Template name:'));
      var list = app.createListBox();
      list.setName('Templates');
      grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);
      var docs = DocsList.getFolder("Templates").getFilesByType("document");
      for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        list.addItem(docs[i].getName(),docs[i].getId());
      }
      grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Row:'));
      var row = app.createTextBox().setName('row');
      row.setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getRow());
      grid.setWidget(1, 1, row);

    ///////////////////////////////This is what i am trying to implement into my UI//////////////////////////////////////////////
       var curFN = app.createTextBox().setText('MyDrive/').setName('curFN').setId('curFN').setWidth('400');
  //var curFID = app.createTextBox().setText('x').setName('curFID').setId('curFID').setWidth('400');
  var listFolder = app.createListBox().setName('list').setId('list').addItem('please select a folder','x');
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('Choose Folder:'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, listFolder);
  var folders = DocsList.getRootFolder().getFolders();
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    list.addItem(folders[i].getName(),folders[i].getId())
  } 
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('folderSelect').addCallbackElement(grid);
  list.addChangeHandler(handler);

  var currentFN = e.parameter.curFN;
  var currentFID = e.parameter.list;
  //Logger.log(currentFID);
  var FolderList = app.getElementById('listFolder');
  var curFN = app.getElementById('curFN');
  //var curFID = app.getElementById('curFID');
  //if(currentFID=='x'){currentFID=DocsList.getRootFolder().getId() ; curFN.setText('MyDrive/')};
  var startFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID);
  var folders = startFolder.getFolders();
  FolderList.clear().addItem('no other subFolder','x').addItem('Go back to Root','x');
  if(folders.length>0){FolderList.clear(); FolderList.addItem('please select a subFolder','x')};
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
   FolderList.addItem(folders[i].getName(),folders[i].getId())
  } 
  curFN.setText(currentFN+DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID).getName()+'/');
  if(currentFID==DocsList.getRootFolder().getId()){curFN.setText('MyDrive/')};
  curFID.setText(currentFID);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
      panel.add(grid);
      var button = app.createButton('Submit');
      var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('generateDocument');
      handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
      button.addClickHandler(handler);

      // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the application app in the Spreadsheet doc
      panel.add(button);
      app.add(panel);
      doc.show(app);
    }
```

---

### EDIT:

Thanks to Serge insas for all of his help he fixed everything and it works perfectly and i would like to share it with all of you if you ever need something that will: Export a row of a spreadsheet document into a work document, put it into a specific folder and create a PDF of that work document. to make the template use {A} {B} and so on where you want to put your information.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
Template Generator By: Andre Fecteau - klutch2013@gmail.com
Original Code From: kiszal@gmail.com (Found in the template gallery by searching "Templates" It is the first One.
Major Help from: Serge Insas On Stack Overflow (He did most of the work.)
Link 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147798/e-undefined-google-script-error
Link 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132837/have-a-listbox-populate-with-every-folder-in-mydrive

How To Use: 
First: each column is designated in your Template by {Column Letter} for example for column A it would be {A}
Second: You can change this, but your Template must be in a folder called "Templates." This folder can be anywhere in your drive.
Third: Click "Generate Documents Here!" Then click "Export Row to Document"
Fourth: Type in the row you want to export. Chose your Folder Path. Click Submit. 
NOTE ON FOURTH STEP: If you want your number to skip the header row add a +1 to line 28. 
This would mean if you typed "2" in the row box it actually exports row 3. I took this out because it can get confusing at times.

NOTE: Line 67 you can edit the word "Templates" to whatever folder you saved your Template into.

Feel free to edit this code as you wish and for your needs. That is what I did with the original code.
So there is no reason I should restrict what others do with this code.
*/

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function generateDocument(e) {
  var template = DocsList.getFileById(e.parameter.Templates);
  Logger.log(template.getName());
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var row = Number(e.parameter.row)//+1 ; // Remove the // in this line next to the +1 to skip headers
  Logger.log(row);
  var currentFID = e.parameter.curFID;
  Logger.log(currentFID);
  var myDocID = template.makeCopy(Sheet.getRange('B'+row).getValue()+' - '+Sheet.getRange('E'+row).getValue()+' - '+Sheet.getRange('D'+row).getValue()+' - '+Sheet.getRange('X'+row).getValue()).getId();
  var myDoc = DocumentApp.openById(myDocID);
  var copyBody = myDoc.getActiveSection();
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  row--; // decrement row number to be in concordance with real row numbers in sheet
  var myRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(row+":"+row);
  for (var i=1;i<Sheet.getLastColumn()+1;i++){
    var myCell = myRow.getCell(1, i);
    copyBody.replaceText("{"+myCell.getA1Notation().replace(row,"")+"}", myCell.getValue());
  }

  myDoc.saveAndClose();
  var destFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID);
  Logger.log(myDocID);
  var doc = DocsList.getFileById(myDocID);// get the document again but using docsList this time...
  doc.addToFolder(destFolder);// add it to the desired folder
  doc.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());// I did it step by step to be more easy to follow
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(myDocID).getAs("application/pdf");
  destFolder.createFile(pdf);// this will create the pdf file in your folder
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getTemplates() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Generate from template');
  // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
  var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Template name:'));
  var list = app.createListBox();
  list.setName('Templates');
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);
  var docs = DocsList.getFolder("Templates").getFilesByType("document"); //Change the word "Templates" to whatever folder you saved your template into
  for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    list.addItem(docs[i].getName(),docs[i].getId());
  }

  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Row:'));
  var row = app.createTextBox().setName('row');
  row.setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getRow());
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, row);
  var curFN = app.createTextBox().setText('MyDrive/').setName('curFN').setId('curFN').setWidth('400');
  var curFID = app.createTextBox().setText(DocsList.getRootFolder().getId()).setName('curFID').setId('curFID').setVisible(false);
  var listF = app.createListBox().setName('listF').setId('listF').addItem('Please Select Folder','x');
  grid.setText(2,0,'Type Path:').setWidget(2,1,curFN).setText(3,0,'OR').setText(4,0, 'Choose Path:').setWidget(4,1,listF).setWidget(3,1,curFID);
  var folders = DocsList.getRootFolder().getFolders();
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    listF.addItem(folders[i].getName(),folders[i].getId())
  } 

  var handlerF = app.createServerHandler('folderSelect').addCallbackElement(grid);
  listF.addChangeHandler(handlerF);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(grid);
  var button = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('generateDocument');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the application app in the Spreadsheet doc
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  doc.show(app);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function folderSelect(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var currentFN = e.parameter.curFN;
  var currentFID = e.parameter.listF;
  Logger.log(currentFID);
  var listF = app.getElementById('listF');
  var curFN = app.getElementById('curFN');
  var curFID = app.getElementById('curFID');
  if(currentFID=='x'){currentFID=DocsList.getRootFolder().getId() ; curFN.setText('MyDrive/')};
  var startFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID);
  var folders = startFolder.getFolders();
  listF.clear().addItem('No More Sub Folders!','x').addItem('Go back to Root','x');
  if(folders.length>0){listF.clear(); listF.addItem('Select Sub Folder','x')};
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    listF.addItem(folders[i].getName(),folders[i].getId())
  } 

  curFN.setText(currentFN+DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID).getName()+'/');
  if(currentFID==DocsList.getRootFolder().getId()){curFN.setText('MyDrive/')};
  curFID.setText(currentFID);
  return app;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function onOpen() {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Export Row to Document", functionName: "getTemplates"}];  
  ss.addMenu("Generate Documents Here!", menuEntries);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not integrate this code the way you did... A `handler` function is a function that is executed when a certain action is done by a user and the `callBackElement` brings values to that function using `e` object (e comes for event information).

If you try to get `e.parameter` in the main code it will try to get a value that is not yet defined and generate the error you get.

Here is a correct implementation of my code in yours, please examine it attentively to see and understand how it works.

```
function getTemplates() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Generate from template');
  // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
  var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Template name:'));
  var list = app.createListBox();
  list.setName('Templates');
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);
  var docs = DocsList.getFolder("Templates").getFilesByType("document");
  for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    list.addItem(docs[i].getName(),docs[i].getId());
  }
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Row:'));
  var row = app.createTextBox().setName('row');
  row.setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getRow());
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, row);
  var curFN = app.createTextBox().setText('MyDrive/').setName('curFN').setId('curFN').setWidth('400');
  var curFID = app.createTextBox().setText('x').setName('curFID').setId('curFID').setVisible(false);
  var listF = app.createListBox().setName('listF').setId('listF').addItem('please select a folder','x');
  grid.setText(2,0,'Choose a folder in your drive').setWidget(2,1,curFN).setWidget(3,1,curFID).setWidget(4,1,listF);
  var folders = DocsList.getRootFolder().getFolders();
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    listF.addItem(folders[i].getName(),folders[i].getId())
  } 
  var handlerF = app.createServerHandler('folderSelect').addCallbackElement(grid);
  listF.addChangeHandler(handlerF);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(grid);
  var button = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('generateDocument');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the application app in the Spreadsheet doc
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  doc.show(app);
}

function folderSelect(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var currentFN = e.parameter.curFN;
  var currentFID = e.parameter.listF;
  Logger.log(currentFID);
  var listF = app.getElementById('listF');
  var curFN = app.getElementById('curFN');
  var curFID = app.getElementById('curFID');
  if(currentFID=='x'){currentFID=DocsList.getRootFolder().getId() ; curFN.setText('MyDrive/')};
  var startFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID);
  var folders = startFolder.getFolders();
  listF.clear().addItem('no other subFolder','x').addItem('Go back to Root','x');
  if(folders.length>0){listF.clear(); listF.addItem('please select a subFolder','x')};
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    listF.addItem(folders[i].getName(),folders[i].getId())
  } 
  curFN.setText(currentFN+DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID).getName()+'/');
  if(currentFID==DocsList.getRootFolder().getId()){curFN.setText('MyDrive/')};
  curFID.setText(currentFID);
  return app;
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

Following your comment, here is the modification to move the document it the chosen folder and create the pdf file as well in the same folder :

```
function generateDocument(e) {
  var template = DocsList.getFileById(e.parameter.Templates);
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var row = e.parameter.row
  var currentFID = e.parameter.listF;
  var myDocID = template.makeCopy(Sheet.getRange('B'+row).getValue()+' - '+Sheet.getRange('E'+row).getValue()+' - '+Sheet.getRange('D'+row).getValue()+' - '+Sheet.getRange('X'+row).getValue()).getId();
  var myDoc = DocumentApp.openById(myDocID);
  var copyBody = myDoc.getActiveSection();
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var myRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(row+":"+row);
  for (var i=1;i<Sheet.getLastColumn()+1;i++){
    var myCell = myRow.getCell(1, i);
    copyBody.replaceText("{"+myCell.getA1Notation().replace(row,"")+"}", myCell.getValue());
  }
  myDoc.saveAndClose();
  var destFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(currentFID);
  var doc = DocsList.getFileById(myDocID);// get the document again but using docsList this time...
  doc.addToFolder(destFolder);// add it to the desired folder
  doc.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());// I did it step by step to be more easy to follow
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(myDocID).getAs("application/pdf");
  destFolder.createFile(pdf);// this will create the pdf file in your folder
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am almost done with this script. The last thing i need is to be able tell the generated file to save in the folder selected with that ListBox.

Comment: Thank you again! i get an error though when i run which i got when i was messing around with the PDF option. it says that no file can be found with the ID.

Comment: Also after your second revision which makes the file save in the selected folder, the UI that generates the button to start the script does not show up anymore. I do not know if it is related or not and i can not figure out why it will not work.

Comment: I fixed the above issue of the menu button not showing up. I had a } bracket in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you still having issues with the PDF file?

Comment: Yes, I am still having issues saving to PDF. I am also having issues with the moving of files, when it tries to run the program at the end if says it can not find the file with the ID.

Comment: If you want you can share a copy of your working sheet with me so I can help to find where it fails... my email is sergegabet  and is a gmail mail

Comment: I have added you to the spreadsheet and the template. thank you!